# Embedding a Pentaho report inside a panel on another web page

Tags: iframe, panel, pentaho

I have a web application that is having a portlet style main page display of multiple display panels. What I'd to have is the ability to embed a Pentaho report in one of these panels. Is this possible?

so Can I embed a Pentaho report inside this panel?
and how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that.  Here's a link to Pentaho's guide on embedding:
http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Freporting_embedders_guide%2Ftopic_introduction.html