# How to integrate Pentaho reporting in struts application

Tags: struts2, pentaho

I have a requirement to generate report in Pentaho, and display in jsp pages (in struts application). If any one know about implementation of Pentaho please Replay...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it. I have done it using Xactions *(in Pentaho version 4.x.x)*. Call the reports in Xactions and then use xaction url from JSP page to embedded it.

Also you can also look at the [Pentaho wiki for embedding and extending reports](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Freporting_embedders_guide%2Ftopic_introduction.html).

There are also similar links :

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?54076-Calling-Pentaho-Reports-From-JSP

[Embedding a Pentaho report inside a panel on another web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855869/embedding-a-pentaho-report-inside-a-panel-on-another-web-page)

[.prpt reports running from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840764/prpt-reports-running-from-java)

The basic idea (*probably*) is to publish the report and call the report using the report URL from the JSP/Java page.

Hope this helps :).